# Is there a better way to make multiple choice look commands in a text based game?

Tags: python

I am making a text based adventure game with commands to look at the environment aswell as details within the environment; I am curious if there is a better way to make multiple choice look commands, maybe some way to lump all the elif statements together as they all do the same thing anyways.

```
if choice == "look river":
        print(f"{Back.BLUE}The water is merky.{Style.RESET_ALL}")
        print(f"{Fore.YELLOW}There is something in the river reflecting sunlight.{Style.RESET_ALL}")
elif choice =="look river bank":
        print(f"{Back.BLUE}The water is merky.{Style.RESET_ALL}")
        print(f"{Fore.YELLOW}There is something in the river reflecting sunlight.{Style.RESET_ALL}")
elif choice =="look water":
        print(f"{Back.BLUE}The water is merky.{Style.RESET_ALL}")
        print(f"{Fore.YELLOW}There is something in the river
```

Comment: Your question is very broad. The answer is "yes", and you should look at boolean operators (`or`, `and`, etc.). You may also want to think ahead a bit - what do other commands look like? Is every command of the form `<verb> <object>` and would it be helpful to split them before testing them?

Comment: FYI, it's `murky`, not `merky`.

Comment: If your Python version is above 3.10, there is a built-in function called `match` statement that you can try

Comment: The PEP tutorial document for match-case actually uses examples directly out of making a text adventure game: https://peps.python.org/pep-0636/

Answer (score 1):

You could create a dictionary with all the different possible 'look' commands:

```py
choices_look = {'look river':"the water is merky\nYou can see your reflection",
"look riverbank":"you have looked at the river bank"}
```

and then use a function to find the correct response to a command:

```py
def get_choice():
    choice = str(input("What do you want to do? ").lower())
    if 'look'in choice:
        for i in choices_look:
            if i == choice:
                print(choices_look[i])
```

This is what I have done in one of my text based games and I found it made the code a lot neater than having a lot of `if` and `elif` statements.

If you wanted the possibility of having more than one response to a command and still use the dictionary then you can make the value a list:

```py
choice_looks = {'look river':['you looked at the river','something else']}
```

You can then choose to only show one of the responses based on a condition or show both whilst the code still being clumped together in a somewhat neat manner.

Hope that helps.